# Compare the presence of files in two directories to third directory in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, directory, compare, diff

How to compare the presence of files in `dir1` and `dir2` to `dir3`.

For example:

```
dir1     dir2     dir3 
file1    file2    file1
file3    file4    file2
file5    file6    file3
file9             file5
                  file6
                  file7
```

and the output to be as below:

```
only in dir1: file9
only in dir2: file4
only in dir3: file7
```

**Edit:**

I am looking to find the differences using the command line, moreover I am using centos 7.

I have used `diff dir1 dir2` to compare two directories, and I have found `diff3` to compare three files but not three directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This small line of unix commands can do that for you. But it only works if your files and directories contain no whitespace:

```
find dir{1..3} -mindepth 1 -type f | tr '/' ' ' | sort -k2,2 | uniq -u -f 1 | sed -e 's/ /: /' -e 's/^/only in /'
```

Find first lists all the directories with its files. Tweak it to your needs, your dirs might not actually be dir1, dir2, and dir3.

Than we replace the '/' of the paths with a space, because `uniq` can only determine fields by whitespace. We sort on the second field (the file). Than we print only the unique lines for the second field, skipping the first field (-f 1). Than we use sed to nicely print the unique paths.

Answer (score 1):

Another variant:

```
find dir*/ -type f | sort -t/ -k2 | uniq -u -s 4 | sort
```

```
dir1/file9
dir2/file4
dir3/file7
```

Cosmetic:

```
find dir*/ -type f | sort -t/ -k2 | uniq -u -s 4 | sort | sed 's/dir/Only in dir/g' | sed 's/\//: /g'
```

```
Only in dir1: file9
Only in dir2: file4
Only in dir3: file7
```

Comment: This is very much like my answer. Also using -s 4 only works if all folder names have the same amount of characters.

Comment: This is not written explicitly in the present question. And I saw you answer after.

Answer (score 1):

In GNU awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGINFILE {
    n=split(FILENAME,t,"/")                    # I should use gensub here too
    f[t[n]]++                                  # count distinct filenames
    p[t[n]]=gensub(/\/[^/]*$/,"",1,FILENAME)   # store path (collisions dont matter)
}
END {
    for(i in f)                                # all files encountered
        if(f[i]==1)                            # look for singles
            printf "only in %s: %s\n", p[i], i # ... and output them 
}' dir1/* dir2/* dir3/*                        # or dir[123]/*
```

Output:

```
only in dir1: file9
only in dir2: file4
only in dir3: file7
```

For non-GNU awks:

```
$ for i in dir[123]/*
do echo $i
done | 
awk -F/ ' {
    t=$NF
    f[t]++
    sub(/\/[^/]*$/,"")
    p[t]=$0
}
END {
    for(i in f)
        if(f[i]==1)
            printf "only in %s: %s\n", p[i], i
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

meld is a good graphical diff frontend that will show you a side-by side listing of files. Install meld with Ubuntu Software Center:

```
sudo apt-get install meld
meld dir1 dir2 dir3
```

Check If this helps you

Comment: Try meld if it works

Answer (score 0):

find with awk :

```
find . -mindepth 2 -name '*' |  
awk -F/ '
  { 
    seen[$NF]++
    path[$NF] = $(NF-1)
  }
  END {
    for(i in seen) {
      if(seen[i]==1)
        print "only in "path[i] ": " i
    }
  }
'
```